# SQL: nested sub queries vs set operiations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am I correct in stating that most nested subqueries are interchangeable with set operators such as `union`, `intersect` etc. in the respect that they will give the same results. Asking as I find set operators a lot easier to use and would prefer to use them over nested subqueries in my upcoming exams.

E.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT course id
  FROM section
 WHERE     semester = ’Fall’
       AND year = 2009
       AND courseid IN (SELECT course id
                          FROM section
                         WHERE semester = ’Spring’ AND year = 2010);
```

Gives same result as:

```
(SELECT course id
   FROM section
  WHERE semester = ’Fall’ AND year = 2009)
INTERSECT
(SELECT course id
   FROM section
  WHERE semester = ’Spring’ AND year = 2010);
```

Comment: This is too broad a statement. Subqueries can be used to achieve the same results as `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, etc. but they have much broader uses.

Comment: If you want further info regarding performance, this might be a good candidate question for moving to the dba realm.

Comment: No you would not be correct.  Sometimes they would be logically equivalent and sometimes they would not.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the method of coding is completely dependent on coding practices followed in an organization. While most of them have defined guidelines about coding, they often leave choices such as your case to be made by developers according to their personal preferences. So, as long as the query gives the correct results, nobody is going to bother whether you have used set operators or subqueries.

There is one more way to write your code, which you seem to have ignored or forgotten. You can use joins and minimize the lines of code further. It would go as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.course_id
  FROM section s1 INNER JOIN section s2 ON s1.courseid = s2.courseid
 WHERE     s1.semester = 'Fall'
       AND s2.semester = 'Spring'
       AND s1.year = 2009
       AND s2.year = 2010;
```

Also, as Szymon has mentioned in a comment above, subqueries have much broader uses. One of them is correlated subqueries. Another great use of subqueries is inline views. Google both of them and try to apply these concepts in your work (if you're not doing this just for college assignments but to learn what coding is).

Answer (score 0):

I ran a quick check against some of my own data just to verify and using your two examples there I got the same results which, in the confines of those examples at least, confirms that they are the same.

For the purposes of an exam, I think you're okay.

In the real world however, these two statements will often yield different execution plans. It's a little hard to write concrete advice about these because the table design and data sizes will be different between all systems. But although you may be comfortable seeing these as returning the same results, it's a bit akin to:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

vs

```
Select column1, column2, column3 FROM mytable
```

With the first one there the performance (and execution plan) will probably be the same for a small table with little data, but as it grows you will start to pay for the few seconds of savings you got by writing short-hand code.

If you search around you'll find people who have performance problems with INTERSECT; I haven't seen anyone with better performance on INTERSECT than using the subquery alternative.